# google map api not working for ajax from 2nd response onwards

Tags: ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application i have to show the path covered by an user in particulat date working fine for first response,from second response from ajax i am getting data which is diffrent from first one but still map showing 1st response result

I included google map javascript api like below in header section of html

```
<script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

I am using following code in my jsp file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   window.setInterval(positionCheck, 20000);

});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById("directions_panel").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = "";
    $("#searchSubmit").onclick(){
        positionCheck();    
    }

});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function positionCheck(){

        var username=$("#xmlLabel").val();
        var searchDate=$("#searchDate").val();
        if(username!=""&& searchDate!=''){
```

This part where i used ajax call working fine for first response
from second response onwards problem arises it is showing content of first response from server

```
         $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "searchLocation.mnt",
            data :"xmlLabel="+username+"&searchDate="+searchDate,
            dataType : "json",
            mimeType : 'application/json',
            success : function(data) {
                if(data!=""){
                    mapLoaded(data);

                    function mapLoaded(data){

                    var size=0;
                    var counts=0;
                      var stops = data;
                      alert(stops);
                        size =stops.length;
                        if(stops.length>0){
                            var mapid=document.getElementById("map");

                        var map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapid);

                        // new up complex objects before passing them around
                        var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true,polylineOptions: {
                          strokeColor: "black"
                        }});
                        var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
                        Tour_startUp(stops);
                        window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
                        window.tour.fitBounds(map);
                        alert(stops.length);
                        if (stops.length > 1)
                            window.tour.calcRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
                        }
                        alert(stops.length);


                        function Tour_startUp(stops) {
                            if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
                                updateStops: function (newStops) {
                                    stops = newStops;
                                },
                                // map: google map object
                                // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)

                                loadMap: function (map, directionsDisplay) {
                                    var myOptions = {
                                        zoom:4,
                                        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(17.379818, 78.478542), // default to Hyderabad
                                        mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    };
                                    map.setOptions(myOptions);
                                    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                                },
                                fitBounds: function (map) {
                                    var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                                    // extend bounds for each record
                                    jQuery.each(stops, function (key, val) {
                                        var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
                                        bounds.extend(myLatlng);
                                    });
                                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                },
                                calcRoute: function (directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
                                    var batches = [];
                                    var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
                                    var itemsCounter = 0;
                                    var wayptsExist = stops.length > 0;

                                    while (wayptsExist) {
                                        var subBatch = [];
                                        var subitemsCounter = 0;

                                        for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops.length; j++) {
                                            subitemsCounter++;
                                            subBatch.push({

                                                location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops[j].latitude, stops[j].longitude),
                                                stopover: true
                                            });
                                            if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                                                break;
                                        }

                                        itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                                        batches.push(subBatch);
                                        wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops.length;
                                        // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                                        // start up with end of previous tour leg
                                        itemsCounter--;
                                    }

                                    // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
                                    var combinedResults;
                                    var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
                                    var directionsResultsReturned = 0;

                                    for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                                        var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                                        var start = batches[k][0].location;
                                        var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                                        // trim first and last entry from array
                                        var waypts = [];
                                        waypts = batches[k];
                                        waypts.splice(0, 1);
                                        waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                                        var request = {
                                            origin: start,
                                            destination: end,
                                            waypoints: waypts,
                                            travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
                                        };
                                        (function (kk) {
                                            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                                                if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                                                    var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                                                    unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                                                    directionsResultsReturned++;

                                                    if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                                                    {
                                                        // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                                        unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                                        var count = 0;
                                                        for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                                            if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                                                if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                                                    if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                                        combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                                                    else {
                                                                        // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                                        // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                                                    }
                                                                    count++;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(combinedResults);
                                                        var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;
                                                        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
                                                        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
                                                        var totdist=0;
                                                        // alert(legs.length);
                                                        for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++){

                                                             var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                                             var markerletter2= "B".charCodeAt(0)
                                                                 markerletter += i;
                                                            markerletter2 += i; 
                                                          markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                                          markerletter2 = String.fromCharCode(markerletter2);
                                                          createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,legs[i].start_address,markerletter);//To display location address on the marker
                                                          var routeSegment = i + 1;
                                                          var point=+routeSegment+1;
                                                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
                                                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Point '+ routeSegment +' :</b>'+ '  ' +legs[i].start_address + ' <br> ';
                                                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Point '+ point +' :</b>'+ '  '+legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                                                          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Distance Covered '+' :</b>'+legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                                                          var test=legs[i].distance.text.split(' ');
                                                          var one=parseFloat(test[0]);
                                                        if(test[1]=="m"){
                                                          var one=parseFloat(test[0]/1000); 
                                                          }
                                                          totdist=parseFloat(totdist)+parseFloat(one);
                                                        }
                                                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b> Total Distance :'+totdist + 'km'+ '</b><br><br>';
                                                        var i=legs.length;
                                                        var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                            markerletter += i;
                                                        markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);
                                                        createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,legs[legs.length-1].end_address,markerletter);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        })(k);
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                          { 
                            size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                          });

                        var icons = new Array();
                        icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
                              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
                              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                              // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
                              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



                        function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {
                            counts++;
                            if(counts==size){
                                var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png";   
                            }else{
                           if (iconStr=="undefined") { 
                              iconStr = "red"; 
                              var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"; 
                           }
                           else{
                                var markerimageLoc="http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker"+ iconStr +".png"; 
                             // var markerimageLoc = "http://www.maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png";   
                           }
                            }
                              icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(markerimageLoc,
                              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
                              new google.maps.Size(25, 34),
                              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                              // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
                              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
                           return icons[iconStr];

                        }
                          // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
                          // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
                          // in the top left of the image.

                          // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
                          // increase in the X direction to the right and in
                          // the Y direction down.

                          var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
                              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
                              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                              // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
                              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
                          var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
                              // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
                              // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
                              new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
                              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
                              // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
                              // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
                              // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
                              // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
                              // coordinate.
                          var iconShape = {
                              coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
                              type: 'poly'
                          };


                        function createMarker(map, latlng, label, character) {
                            var markerletter=character;
                               if( /[^a-zA-Z]/.test( character ) ) {
                                   var markerletter="undefined";
                                } 

                            var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>';
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng,
                                map: map,
                                shadow: iconShadow,
                                icon: getMarkerImage(markerletter),
                                shape: iconShape,
                                title: label,
                                zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
                                });
                                marker.myname = label;

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
                                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                });
                            return marker;
                        } 
                }
                }else{


                }
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e,"Alert Box");
            }
        });  
        }
    }
    </script>
```

and i included div tag like this in body section

```
 <div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac; height: 500px;"
            class="col-sm-6"></div>
```

above code working fine if i am not using ajax,problem exist only for ajax

Comment: Can you clarify what problem comes up exactly? What doesn't work, what happens? Any errors in the error console?

Comment: Please read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: no error when it is showing the results of 1 respone from ajax.. in brief if am getting 4 list of latlongs from first respone no problem with result .From second response if am getting 10 list of latlongs map is not updating it is showing previous results on map..thanks for your quick reply@Pekka

Comment: Is the response being cached?

Comment: no it is not catching  the 2nd response sorry for the late reply@geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry to trouble all of you,i feel very silly that  i declared variable of stops globally and i need to call methods like below

```
  function initialize(data) {
    size = 0;
    counts = 0;
    var map=0;
     var stops = data;
        size = stops.length;
        if (stops.length > 0) {
            var map = new window.google.maps.Map(document
                    .getElementById("map"));
            // new up complex objects before passing them around
            var directionsDisplay = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
                    {
                        suppressMarkers : true,
                        polylineOptions : {
                            strokeColor : "black"
                        }
                    });
            var directionsService = new window.google.maps.DirectionsService();
            Tour_startUp(stops);
            window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay);
```

i changed the below methods from  window.tour.fitBounds(map); window.tour.calcRoute(stops,directionsService,
                            directionsDisplay); to

```
            window.tour.fitBounds(map,stops);
            if (stops.length > 1)
                window.tour.calcRoute(stops,directionsService,
                        directionsDisplay);
        }
}
```